# imacro extracting help needed

Tags: extract, imacros

I'm using a simple script in imacro to extract some text.
Most times the text have a `.` in it

so if I want to extract `10.000`, I don't want the `.` in it.
I have it like this

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:maintxt EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
```

The extracting works fine but then I get `10.000` extracted.
And I don't want the `.`

Does someone know how to remove the `.` before entering in the form?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple:

```
TAG POS=2 TYPE=TD ATTR=CLASS:maintxt EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.replace(/\\./g, '');")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:CONTENT={{!EXTRACT}}
```

Comment: After doing this it place {{!EXTRACT} in the form. And not the 10.000 that i'm extracting.